# Memory metrics not showing any data for GCP Windows instances

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I have installed the Stackdriver agent on my GCE windows instance by following the documentation.

https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/install-agent

And I can see metrics for CPU, Networking and Disk IO are working fine, however Memory metrics are not showing any data. Do I have to enable these metrics or is it because I do not have an external/public IP?

Working metrics image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xc97Y.jpg

I have not added any credentials for Stackdriver, because the documentation says:

> GCP VM instances generally have the correct credentials by default.

I can confirm the Agent monitoring service is running on windows, but still not memory data on the metrics/charts.

Please give me some hints on how to get these metrics working?

Comment: Which agent did you install?

Comment: In Compute Engine, what scopes did you setup?

Comment: I installed StackdriverMonitoring-GCM-46.exe in silent mode

Comment: Install Stackdriver logging also, this will help confirm that you have the right permissions setup.

Comment: John, I can see the scopes disabled
Stackdriver Logging API Disabled
Stackdriver Monitoring API Disabled
But the documentation does not mention anything about enabling these.

I

Comment: Did you enable them?

Comment: Yes, and I was confirming if it was all working good, and indeed that was missing part. Logging agent is working and Monitoring agent showing memory metrics.

To finish, quick question: Write only should be the right permission, right?

Comment: I am not understanding what you are saying (language translation?). If your question is what IAM role you need for Stackdriver logging - yes, write permission.

Comment: The appropriate value for monitoring and logging scopes in compute engine should be "write only"?